# Find a function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ s.t $f(a)+f(b)=f(a)$ $\forall a>b$, $f(a)>f(b)$ $\forall a>b$.

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

Define a function $f$ that satisfies:

$f(a)+f(b)=f(a)$ $\forall a>b$

and

$f(a)>f(b)$ $\forall a>b.$

The answer says such function does not exist but does not say why.

---

Let $f(x)=\lim_{\alpha\to\infty}-e^{-\alpha x}$. $a$ is tending to positive infinite. Obviously it satisfies the conditions. I believe anyone took first year calculus knows how compare the magnitute of two infinities.

http://library.umac.mo/ebooks/b31290735.pdf

Comment: first condition implies $f \equiv 0$ but this contradicts second condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f(a) + f(b) = f(a)$ for all $a > b$ that means $f(b) = 0$ for every number that has a number larger than it.

*All* number have numbers larger than it, so $f(b) = 0$ for all $b$.

So $f(a) = f(b)$ which contradicts $f(a) > f(b)$ if $a > b$.

....

If that's not convincing consider $3 > 2 > 1$  So $f(3) + f(2) = f(3)$ and $f(3) +f(1) = f(3)$ and $f(2) + f(1) = f(2)$.  And $f(3) > f(2) > f(1)$.  Is that possible?

$f(3) + f(2) = f(3)$ means $f(3) + f(2) -f(3) =f(3) - f(3)$ means $f(2) =0$.  And $f(3) + f(1) = f(3)$ means $f(1) =0$.  And $f(2) +f(1) =f(2)$ means $f(1) =0$.  So $f(3) > 0 > 0$.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 5):

The implication is that

$$f(b)=0$$

for all $b<a$. Let $a=1$, so $f(b)=0$ for $b<1$. However, we require that $f(0)>f(-1)$, which is not true. Thus, no such function can exist.

Answer (score 1):

You had an answer about why a function with these conditions doesn't exist.
But for the function you proposed, it doesn't work because for example you have that

$2>1$ but $f(2)=f(1)=0$

And you mentioned something about comparing infinities but the range of your function is the set $\mathbb R$ $$f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$$
And $\infty \not\in \mathbb R$ so I don't think that, in this case, it is right to say that $f(-1)>f(-2)$ eventhough 'as infinities' it is right that here $\infty>\infty$

So the function that you proposed doesn't fulfill the conditions too

Comment: $f(2)>f(1)$ obviously. Recall first year calculus what you need to do to compare two infinity or infinitismal, $f(2)/f(1)>1$. For another example, you cannot just $\lim_{x\to 0}x^2$ is same as $\lim_{x\to 0}x$ just because they are both tending to zero.

Comment: @High GPA, this is false, because when you use the 'limit' it is right to say that $\lim_{x \to 0} x=\lim_{x \to 0} x^2$ eventhough $x \ne x^2$ as function. But $0^2=0$. You can review the exact definition of a limit, because for example $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{x}$ is exactly $0$, not near $0$ as you are considering. And similarly $\lim_{x \to 0} x^2$ is exactly $0$ and near it